# Unable to load data to Postgres using Kafka JDBC Sink Connector

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have brought data from RDS postgres to kafka topic using debezium source connector. Data in topic looks like below:

```
{"domain":"domain-new-34B","profile":"2423947a-asf23424","account":"aasdfadf","customer":"gaf23sdf","profileno":"324","user":"234234","updatedat":233463463456,"__deleted":"false"}
```

I am using Kafka JDBC sink connector to send data to Cloudsql Postgres. My sink connector .json file looks like below:

```
{
"name":"postgres-sink-connector",
"config":{
    "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max":1,
    "auto.create":true,
    "connection.url":"jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/testdb",
    "connection.user":"user1",
    "connection.password":"user123",
    "topics":"server1.public.topic1",
    "auto.create":"true",
    "auto.evolve":"true",
    "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
    "transforms": "flatten",
    "transforms.flatten.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value",
    "transforms.flatten.delimiter": ".",
    "table.name.format": "${topic}",
    "transforms": "route",
    "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
    "transforms.route.replacement": "$2_$3",
    "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState"
}
```

}

Getting below error when posting connector:

```
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Sink connector 'postgres-sink-connector' is configured with 'delete.enabled=false' and 'pk.mode=none' and therefore requires records with a non-null Struct value and non-null Struct schema, but found record at (topic='server1.public.topic1',partition=0,offset=0,timestamp=1212312441756) with a HashMap value and null value schema.
```

I have not created destination table and i want it to be autocreated.

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/591 It seems theres a bug around this. Maybe its the same issue you're facing

Answer (score 0):

Matthias - it drew my attention that  "transforms.flatten.delimiter": ".". Regarding the PostgreSQL db, "." is NOT allowed in the column name. Column Names in PostgreSQL must begin with a letter (a-z) or underscore (_).
The subsequent characters in a name can be letters, digits (0-9), or underscores.

Besides, you have "auto.create" repeated twice in your configuration. One is enough.